# Using gzip compression with mysqldump

Tags: php, gzip, mysql

Can anyone provide an example of how I can include a path to my zip compression software within the following php code? The code works when dumping into a simple sql file, however, gzip compression obviously relies on including the correct path.

```
$dumpfile = $dbname . ".sql.gz"; 

passthru("c:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe --opt --host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpwd $dbname | gzip -v -9 > $dumpfile");
```

Comment: Why are you using `passthru()` with redirection?

Comment: I assumed this was the correct method to employ. I have come across many examples of this, just not a full explanation about how to incorporate gzip compression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the `-c` option to gzip that tells it to output to standard output. Otherwise it expects to operate on files.

use `... | gzip -9 -c > $dumpfile`